# WPF multiple pages with common UI methods

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an WPF application with multiple pages. Each page contains multiple TextBoxes. For the TextBoxes I have different methods for TextChanging, GotFocus, ...

I want to use a common class for all these methods. I tried to create a class `TextBoxHelpers.cs`, a `ResourceDictionary` with `<local:TextBoxHelpers x:Key="TextBoxHelpers"/>` inside and use it by setting `TextChanging="{StaticResource TextBoxHelpers.tbInput_TextChanging_Decimal}"` but it doesn't work.

What is the correct approach for using TextBox methods on multiple pages?

Comment: Can you just use a `UserControl`?

Comment: `UserControl` would be possible. Is this the best way to re-use UI methods?

Comment: You could create a static class for your helper methods. UserControls are a good option too if your methods are associated with particular controls. Yet another way to do this is to create behaviors.

Comment: A static class was my first idea, but I didn't get it working. Thinking about what I want to do `UserControl` is probably the better solution. Thanks guys.